# How can I create a task to run the URL to the current file

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I am using vscode to do some light php programming. I want to be able to create a task that will open the URL to the current file (which is served from my local webserver).

Here is the contents of my tasks.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",
    "isShellCommand": false,
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "args": ["localhost/PhpProject1/${fileBasename}"]
}
```

This works fine for any file located in the document root. However this won't work if the file is located in sub-directories under the document root. Is there any way to make this work for any file?

I have a feeling there is no solution to my answer because vscode doesn't really no where the document root is so it doesn't know how to get the relative path. But I'm hoping there is some kind of configuration that will make it do what I want.

Thanks.

Comment: vscode couldn't care less about the structure of your site. it's just running a program (chrome), and passing a command line argument (some text that happens to be a url). perhaps if `args` was `http://localhost/....` to tell chrome that you want to do an http request, and not load up some local plain text file, it'd work

Comment: @MarcB Yea that is what I thought. It already works without using `http://` but it doesn't work in the file is in a subdirectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hard coding it to look for the filename in the root folder. $Filebasename is just the name of the current file, not the relative path from the root.
See these parameters:

- ${workspaceRoot} the path of the folder opened in VS Code
- ${file} the current opened file
- ${fileBasename} the current opened file's Basecamp
- ${fileDirname} the current opened file's dirname
- ${fileExtname} the current opened file's extension
- ${cwd} the task runner's current working directory on startup

You will need to pass the path/to/file in addition to the file name. If you just did ${file}, it would be the full path... I am not sure if ${fileDirname} includes the full path, or just the relative path from ${workspaceRoot}

If it is the full path, you may need to make a test script that parses the path and converts it the ${workspaceRoot} part into localhost